# Foreach loop for children skipping to last child in XML file

Tags: php, xml

Okay, my script is supposed to open an XML file, recursively loop through all the tags, children, children of children, and so forth spitting out information as we go. Today I noticed an interesting bug in that my foreach loop that is supposed to loop through the children is skipping directly to the last child and I really have no clue as to why.

```
function theHunt($node)
{
    $tagName = '';
    print 'I am starting with ' . $node->getName() . ' It should have ' . $node->count() . ' children. The first child should be: ' . $node->children()->getName() . '<br>';

    foreach ($node->children() as $child);
    {
        print $child->getName() . '<br>';
        if (isset($child))
        {
            print 'I found: ' . $child->getName() . ' I\'ll see if it has kids' . '<br>';
            $this->theHunt($child);
        }
        else
        {
            print 'No kids here, I\'m going to stop digging.<br>';
        }
        //Now that I am all the way down or working my way back up. I start gathering my information.
        $tagName = $node -> getName();
        if($this->rootNode->$tagName[0] !== NULL)
        {
            foreach ($this->rootNode->$tagName[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) ;
            {
                //echo $a, '="', $b, "<br>";
            }
        }
        //print_r($node);
        print'<br> I kicked out <br>';

    }
}
```

The really weird part is that the line:

```
print 'I am starting with ' . $node->getName() . ' It should have ' . $node->count() . ' children. The first child should be: ' . $node->children()->getName() . '<br>';
```

Is outputting all the correct information, but the moment I drop into the foreach loop I skip right to the very last child.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is mishandling the tree structure. You should follow the structure below:

```
function theHunt($node)
{
    foreach ($node->children() as $child);
    {
        if (isset($child))
        { //has children
          theHunt($child); //go one level down
        }
        else
        { //this is a child
          //enum thru its attributes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did nothing. Can you explain why/how I am mishandling the tree though? Maybe if I know how I am I can fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I figured it out. Really rookie mistake. I put a semicolon after my foreach. Took it out, I'm running beautifully.